# How do I connect two switches with two lights?

Tags: electrical

How do I wire two switches and two lights such that the second light can only be turned on if the first light is on? The second switch has no effect on the first light.

Comment: in series. `Hot ----/ ----/ ----- Light`, where "/ -" is a switch.

Answer (score 4):

Note that colors here are the usual colors for US **cables**. If you are in another country, colors may vary. In addition, if you are using *conduit* then you can use different colors (but still use white for neutral):

Everything everywhere gets ground (green or bare). All grounds are connected, never switched, so ignored for this description.

- From circuit breaker, black (hot) and white (neutral)
- Switch 1:

  - Black from circuit breaker to one screw on switch
  - Other screw on the switch gets a short black pigtail
  - Pigtail connects to two black wires
  - White from circuit breaker gets connected to two white wires
- Light 1 gets a black (switched hot) and white (neutral) pair coming from switch 1
- Switch 2 gets a black (switched hot) and white (neutral) pair coming from switch 1. The black goes to one screw. Another black for the 2nd light goes to the other screw. The white wires (one from switch 1, one for the 2nd light) are connected together.
- Light 2 gets the black (double-switched hot) and white (neutral) coming from switch 2.

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome! I'll try this now. It's  for a Halloween prop and i just haven't  been able to make it work.

Comment: If it is a prop and not permanent wiring then that first part would go to a plug instead of a receptacle. But keep in mind that with 120V (or 240V or anything other than low voltage DC) any switches, junctions, etc. need to be properly protected - best solution typically to mount any switches on boxes *as if* they were going in a wall even if they are sitting out. Not 100% code but reasonably safe compared to bare switches with tape over them.

Comment: Yes, it's not permanent...just a plug with small base light sockets and two toggle switches. All connections covered with elec tape...mounted on a wooden box.

Comment: You may already be doing these things, but if not: 1 - Use wire nuts for actual connections, not tape. Tape is good as an extra safeguard but wire nuts are far more reliable for the actual connection between wires and they are *not* expensive; (but covering screw connections with electrical tape is a good idea if any chance of exposed connections); 2 - all connections to the switches should be inside boxes rather than exposed - that's to prevent a loose connection from becoming dangerous.

Comment: Good call on the wire nuts. And I just happen to have a boxful. This is awesome....thanks again...wiring it now.